# Welcome to new users, HN edition

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, new-users

We've had 13 new users in the two hours since [this Hacker News story](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2326545) was posted.

Should any of them chance to look at Meta, welcome to tex.sx.

I wonder if Hacker News is a good place to attract Texthusiasts?  That HN link is a discussion item, which is maybe not the best kind of referral for us.

Comment: Oh my, and that Hacker News is based on this now closed post [Why are there no alternatives to TeX, or, why is TeX still used?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13370/1235)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, also Hacker News is a good place for linking to interesting questions on our site.

- TeX users who don't know TeX.SX yet may visit here and join.
- Follow-up comments on the Hacker News site can be interesting for us.

However, I suggest to link to good stories, not to subjective discussions. Good stories can be

- Great and profound questions
- Great Answers
- Site news posted and discussed on the meta site
- [External stories regarding TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/online-reviews-and-reports-on-tex-sx) you found on other sites
- In the future, [posts on the TeX.SX blog](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1460/what-would-you-like-to-read-in-a-tex-sx-blog)