# Online reviews and reports on TeX.SX

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

- Did you see a review of our TeX.SX site in the web?
- Did you read blog posts or news articles about TeX.SX?
- Do you know that somebody wrote a report about questions or answers on TeX.SX?

Then please post a link to it here. It would be nice to see who writes about TeX.SX, and what. It's also a chance to add comments on the other sites, if meaningful.

*This topic is Community Wiki, so feel free to edit answers adding links.*

Answer (score 3):

I'll make start with

### About TeX.SX

Texts about the site in general

**Blog posts**

- [A new place for TeX questions](http://www.texdev.net/2010/08/02/a-new-place-for-tex-questions/) (Some TeX Developments)
- [TeX and friends get the StackOverflow treatment](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~leingang/content/tex-and-friends-get-stackoverflow-treatment) (Matthew Leingang's blog)
- [New (La)TeX Q&A Site](http://latex-my.blogspot.com/2010/08/new-l-t-e-x-q-site.html) (Malaysian LaTeX User Group)
- [TeX, LaTeX and Friends - a new Q&A site](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/online/stackoverflow/) (texblog.net)
- [{TeX} site launched with new design](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/latex-general/tex-stackexchange-launch/) (texblog.net)
- [“TeX, LaTeX and Friends” StackExchange site also looking for people](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/tex-latex-and-friends-stackexchange-site-also-looking-for-people/) (Secret Blogging Seminar)

**Other texts**

- [TeX/LaTeX Stack Exchange](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1997691) (hacker news)
- [Proposal of a new Q&A site centered on LaTeX](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/23c40e924b3ebab1/) (comp.text.tex)
- [TeX.Stackexchange.com group](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/3719825cf9147e57) (comp.text.tex)

Comment: In other words, us lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

### Questions from TeX.SX, reviewed and discussed on other sites

- [Why is TeX still used? What are some good, modern alternatives?](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2326545)  (hacker news)
- [What led you to TeX and LaTeX?](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2513116) (hacker news)
- [TikZ questions and answers](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/graphics/tikz-questions-answers/) (texblog.net)

Answer (score 1):

Jim Hefferon has written [an article](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100heff.pdf) in the latest [TUGBoat](http://tug.org/tugboat/) reviewing the major English-language online TeX forums. TeX.SX features as one of the big players. (Note: the article is currently available only to TUG members, but will be I open-access after 'about one year'.)